# Mono ASM Generation

Tags: assembly, mono, binary, nasm

I want to try write a simple kernel in C# like cosmos, just for learning. Is it possible to generate x86 or x86-64 ASM from a Mono assembly? because mono --full-aot generates an executable...

After the generation of the ASM I need to compile it with NASM. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're writing a kernel, you'll need a bootstrapper of some kind. If that's written in managed code, your bootstrapper is going to need to include the runtime. Good luck fitting that in the boot sector.

Comment: Nah, I'm going to use ISOLinux and some C code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

mono --aot=asmonly foo.exe